# Possible to earn "Vox Populi" badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

In my mouse over profile summary it says I have 39 votes casted today. When I try to cast another vote (regardless if question or answer) my vote is rejected and a yellow box says my daily vote limit is reached.
Although the badge description says

> Used the maximum 40 votes in a day

How I am able to earn the Vox Populi badge if I'm not able to cast the 40th vote?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get 40 votes a day; of which 10 are question-only and 30 are for use on anything.

The unintuitive thing about how this works is you must use at all 10 question votes up *before* you use up the 30 anything-votes. In fact, once you reach the "only 5 votes left!" warnings (which appear when you start running out of anything-votes) your limit is set for the day, a spree of question votes then won't help.

So, the way to get to 40 votes in a single day is to vote for more questions, so that you've voted for at least 10 before the "N votes left" countdown appears.

---

See the following on Meta.SO for some more information and discussion:

- [Please don't require answer votes to be cast before question votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes)
- [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

Comment: This is **strange**! Guess no badge for me today - lets see tomorrow if I understood that right :D