# Increase daily vote limits depending on a user's reputation

Tags: feature-request, voting

According to [this post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/possible-to-earn-vox-populi-badge/3126#3126), you get 40 votes a day. This seems like a good limit, but I find myself hitting the limit everyday. There are so many questions on Arqade, and so little votes to cast.

I think it would be a good idea to increase the voting limit based on your reputation. For example, 15 reputation lets you vote the minimum, 50 lets you vote more than that, and so on.

I'd like to know if anyone else has the same problem or maybe I am just voting too much. Please feel free to also leave ideas.

Comment: Maybe consider raising your standards?

Comment: If you want changes to the voting system, you're better off suggesting this on Meta Stack Exchange, as it would be a network wide change. However, it's likely been suggested many times before, so I'd also be prepared for the community to downvote/comment liberally, as it would be a repeated inquiry.

Comment: I'm with LessPop. Vote more discerningly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Whilst I agree in principle with LessPop and Frank about voting for quality, I think it's a bit much for them to tell you outright how to use your votes. They are **your** votes, you should vote however you please. The caveat to this however is that you'll be one of the outliers on the voting bell curve (being one who regularly hits the vote limit), thus it's unlikely that 'raising the bar' will be the popular community opinion.

Comment: @Robotnik thank you

Comment: @Robotnik If you regularly hit the voting limit, the answer isn't to increase the voting limit.  It's to be a little less liberal in your voting standards.  Yeah, everyone can vote however they please, but at the end of the day, this is your limit.  Spend it wisely.

Comment: @Frank - Yes, exactly - I agree that raising the vote limit is a bad idea. I also agree that votes should be based on quality of post. What I didn't agree with was some people telling other people **how** to vote. Even the most "strictest-sense of quality" user can hit the cap in a day, just by browsing a large number of questions. The point I was making is that hitting the vote cap regularly makes the OP an exception not the rule, and based on this, that it's unlikely that raising the bar to 50, 60, whatever votes is not going to be popular with the community at large.

Comment: @Robotnik hitting the limit here on Arqade is a sure sign the user might wanna raise his standards. There's not enough questions and answers deserving upvotes in a day to hit... IMO. We're far from the outflow of questions [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) generates which makes it quite easier to hit the limit... well... nevermind.

Comment: Maybe my standards are not high enough, but I do look at lots of questions everyday to try to spend my votes more wisely.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau - As of writing, there are [130,710 posts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A1) (questions and answers) with a score >= 1 on Arqade. Even if we stopped taking questions, and  OP maxed out their daily limit of 40 **every day**, it would take them **3267.5 days**, or almost **9 years** to exhaust the *current supply* of posts. Arqade is just about at the 6 year mark, and assuming that the question rate remains static as well (it wont), by the time the OP upvotes every current post, there'll be 1.5x more of them to have fun with as well.

Comment: (cont.) and these are just the posts that other people found helpful (hence score > 1). I know, a post's current score should have little bearing on how one votes, but it's a good example space of what might be deemed a 'quality post'. (Note I'm also ignoring the *'40 = 10 questions 30 answers'* situation for simplicity's sake, but you get the picture.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Voting too much" is a weird concept. Your votes are yours to use however you see fit. For me, personally, I have never hit the vote limit (or even come close). I don't vote very much, and have high standards when I do usually.

Arqade, on the whole, is a very vote happy community as opposed to many other SE sites. In my experience, rep is gained quicker here than most other places, and questions and answers have higher scores. Especially if you compare to say StackOverflow. It's probably why no one has ever earned the [Unsung Hero](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/unsung-hero) badge on this site.

The vote limit exists for a few reasons. Not the least of which is to avoid people gaming the system, but there are also other systems in place to prevent that and more reasons than that to keep it there. Scaling it up as rep increases would bypass the reasons this limit exists in the first place.

If you are hitting the limit every day, that's perfectly fine. Some people are just vote happy. But, I would encourage you to make sure you are using your votes wisely (however you define that). Voting is the way to keep good content on the top, and sink bad content down. But continually voting in the extreme reduces the effectiveness of the point system by dichotomizing the results into similar extremes. It weeds out the middle and puts everything into "good" or "bad" buckets when some things are really just "ok", some are "great", and some are "terrible".

This, of course, is all in the worst case scenario. Your voting patterns are unlikely to tilt the scale towards this (another reason for a voting limit) it's just something to think about.

---

**Bottom line:** Your votes are yours to do with as you please. If you're hitting the limit regularly, you might want to double check your voting, but it overall isn't a big deal. As for raising the limit, I highly doubt that is going to happen for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D